# Observable ForEachAsync wait for all to be completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, observable

I have the following code:

```
static async Task TestTwo()
{
    int x = 0;

    // The table writer is going to be faster 
    var ab = new ActionBlock<int>(async item =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(30);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref x);

    },
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, BoundedCapacity = 10 });

    await MyObservable().ForEachAsync(async i =>
    {
        await ab.SendAsync(i); // if the ActionBlock is full, this will complete when it has some room
    });

    await Task.Delay(10); // just to let it get ahead a little
    ab.Complete();
    await ab.Completion; // all items proccess by action block
    Console.WriteLine("Test two {0}", x);
}

static IObservable<int> MyObservable()
{
    return Observable.Create<int>(async o =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
            o.OnNext(i);
        }
        o.OnCompleted();
    });
}
```

This will output **241**, but if I change `await ab.SendAsync(i)` to `ab.SendAsync(i).Wait()` then it will output **500**. I guess it's due to it just carrying on and it will run any code after `await ab.SendAsync(i)`. I would expect the wait returned from `ForEachAsync` would also wait for everything it called.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you using this code in the first place? You don't need such code to post to an ActionBlock. What does `MyObservable` do and how many events does it produce? In any case, calling `Wait()` on an asynchrnous method is *definitely* bad.

Comment: If you want to connect an Observable with a DataFlow block, you need to *subscribe* to it, not use `ForEachAsync`, and propagate completions and errors to the block itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is just some code to reproduce my issue. The ActionBlock inserts into some Azure Tables and the Observable is produced from a Cosmos database.

Comment: Check [Mixing TPL Dataflow with Reactive Extensions](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2013/01/31/mixing-tpl-dataflow-with-reactive-extensions/). You can create an observer from a block with `AsObserver()`, eg `var observer=myBlock.AsObserver();`. Once you have this you can use `myObservable.Subscscribe(observer)` to push events from the observable to the block.

Comment: As for this specific problem, what is `MyObservable` going to do if the block isn't fast enough and fills up? `ForEachAsync` won't pause the observable.

Comment: Just tried `myObservable.Subscscribe(observer)` and the does not wait, I did have a version that used an `AutoResetEvent` wait but `Subscscribe(observer)` does not offer the OnCompleted argument .

Comment: ofc, I can just do this with a `Subscscribe` and use an `AutoResetEvent` just does not feel right.